# Try to select but leave blank if fail

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have a request where I select `name, id, date, priority` etc and I also select `category`, since the category is in another table I link it with `JOIN`, the problem is the `category` can be empty and if it's empty there is no `ID`, no `ID` means the `JOIN` doesn't work and it will not display the ticket with no category since it can't select the category name, is there a way to "try" to select the category name and if it can't it leaves the category name blank but still select the other items?

Comment: You want an *outer* join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Outer join didn't work, shows nothing when I replace `JOIN itilcategories ON itilcategories.id = tickets.itilcategories_id` by `OUTER JOIN itilcategories ON itilcategories.id = tickets.itilcategories_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data you provided a left Join will work.

Using these two tables:

```
    |Tickets                      |
    +--+--------+----------+------+
    |ID|Name    |Date      |Cat_id|
    +--+--------+----------+------+
    |1 |Ticket 1|2013-07-13|1     |
    +--+--------+----------+------+
    |2 |Ticket 2|2013-06-13|2     |
    +--+--------+----------+------+
    |3 |Ticket 3|2013-06-25|4     |
    +--+--------+----------+------+

    |Category   |
    +--+--------+
    |ID|Name    |
    +--+--------+
    |1 |sample 1|
    +--+--------+
    |2 |sample 2|
    +--+--------+
    |3 |sample 3|
    +--+--------+
```

Using this query gives what you are looking for:

```
    SELECT t.id, t.name
    ,t.date, c.name FROM `stack overflow`.tickets as t
     Left Join category as c on c.id = t.cat_id
```

The results I got are:

```
    |ID|Name    |Date      |Name    |
    +--+--------+----------+--------+
    |1 |Ticket 1|2013-07-13|Sample 1|
    +--+--------+----------+--------+
    |2 |Ticket 2|2013-06-13|Sample 2|
    +--+--------+----------+--------+
    |3 |Ticket 3|2013-06-25|NULL    |
    +--+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: The problem is the join is for the ID's, I select the category name after the join

Comment: Can you give us an example of what your data looks like?  Two or three lines from each table would be helpful.

Comment: in the table `tickets` I have `id` `name` `date` `category_id` and in the table `category` I have `id` and `name` my full query is a bit complex so I'm just giving you the informations I think you need. I select tickets.id tickets.name tickets.date category.name and I JOIN category ON tickets.category_id = category.id like I said the problem is when there is no category the id in ticket.category_id is empty and it can't select category.name

Comment: Edited my first post with entire query so you can try to see what's wrong